# Django + Celery application on Heroku works locally but worker timeout when deployed

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I have a Django + Celery application using RabbitMQ that works fine locally (when calling `heroku local`), but fails to execute tasks when deployed. There seems to be an a 'worker timeout' that occurs each time the task is called. The versions of the components: Django (3.0.1), celery (4.4.0).

The Heroku logs:

```
2020-01-21T15:38:48.828631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="<REDACTED>" host=<REDACTED> request_id=c59b92be-9b39-4a36-a1d0-e646c9b1f694 fwd="<REDACTED> " dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-01-21T15:38:49.822330+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-21 15:38:49 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10)
2020-01-21T15:38:49.823866+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-21 23:38:49 +0800] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-01-21T15:38:49.982428+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-21 15:38:49 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
```

The RabbitMQ worker according to the logs seems to be running fine:

```
2020-01-21T15:33:53.899791+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2020-01-21 23:33:53,899: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
2020-01-21T15:33:54.969851+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2020-01-21 23:33:54,969: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
2020-01-21T15:33:55.055792+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2020-01-21 23:33:55,055: INFO/MainProcess] celery@aaec950b-24bd-4d29-8c43-c8eeb71e58de ready.
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn gotcha.wsgi --log-level debug
worker: celery -A gotcha worker -l info
```

I've tried running a simple task (just prints a string) on Heroku via the `heroku run python manage.py shell` command, and that also seemed to run without stopping.

The task:

```py
@task()
def test():
    print("test")
```

Force exiting results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 43, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 137, in _connect
    host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 344, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 283, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 839, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 794, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 130, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 311, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 77, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 148, in _connect
    "failed to resolve broker hostname"))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 161, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 425, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 568, in apply_async
    **options
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 771, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 559, in send_task_message
    **properties
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 181, in publish
    exchange_name, declare,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 518, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 187, in _publish
    channel = self.channel
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 209, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 45, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 224, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 868, in default_channel
    self.ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 430, in ensure_connection
    callback, timeout=timeout)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 358, in retry_over_time
    sleep(1.0)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

EDIT 1:
I'm using the CloudAMQP add-on. I tried running heroku locally, but this time, with the CloudAMQP URL supplied by the add-on. The first time I ran it, there was a worker time-out, but in subsequent attempts, tasks are just not being received. Thus, **the issue has something to do with using CLoudAMQP**. I'm using the **free tier**.

As soon as I change the `CELERY_BROKER_URL` to the locally hosted RabbitMQ, all the tasks seem to be received:

```
12:13:32 PM worker.1 |  [2020-01-22 12:13:32,021: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: accounts.tasks.send_targets_and_codes[fe363114-b058-4486-81ca-cb2bac6cc48c]  ETA:[2020-01-22 12:01:00+08:00] 
12:13:32 PM worker.1 |  [2020-01-22 12:13:32,022: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: accounts.tasks.send_targets_and_codes[1de3aef0-bb10-41cf-b133-0cb3f2b2c34d]  ETA:[2020-01-22 12:06:00+08:00] 
12:13:32 PM worker.1 |  [2020-01-22 12:13:32,023: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: accounts.tasks.send_targets_and_codes[9dd9631d-0bb3-468e-91c0-abfa83ab940e]  ETA:[2020-01-22 12:16:00+08:00] 
12:13:32 PM worker.1 |  [2020-01-22 12:13:32,150: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task accounts.tasks.send_targets_and_codes[1de3aef0-bb10-41cf-b133-0cb3f2b2c34d] succeeded in 0.024096399996778928s: None
12:13:32 PM worker.1 |  [2020-01-22 12:13:32,150: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task accounts.tasks.send_targets_and_codes[fe363114-b058-4486-81ca-cb2bac6cc48c] succeeded in 0.024374700005864725s: None
12:13:32 PM worker.1 |  [2020-01-22 12:13:32,186: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task accounts.tasks.send_targets_and_codes[2c891064-17d8-479b-8849-682889d75d8b] succeeded in 0.06000789999961853s: None
```

EDIT 2: It turns out that if my local RabbitMQ server was running, even though I had set the broker URL to that of the CloudAMQP one, tasks would still be sent to the local one. However, upon shutting off the local server, I get the dreaded

```
1:04:48 PM web.1    |  [2020-01-22 13:04:48 +0800] [10964] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11003)
1:04:48 PM web.1    |  [2020-01-22 13:04:48 +0800] [11003] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11003)
1:04:48 PM web.1    |  [2020-01-22 13:04:48 +0800] [11005] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11005
```

EDIT 3: I tried using a local redis server and the exact same `WORKER TIMEOUT` error occurs. The worker DOES seem to be connected to redis.

Here's the very unusual thing however. If there is also a RabbitMQ local server running, the tasks will be picked up by that server (and so the `WORKER TIMEOUT` error does not occur). This leads me to believe that there is something to do with Celery being preconfigured toward RabbitMQ only (and not even CloudAMQP!).